# Python Installation Manager

Tags: python, distutils

Often when I install .exe files made from python files I get an installation manager that is blue and has the logo "python powered". What is the name of this manager? I'd like to use it to make some installable python files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called [distutils](http://docs.python.org/library/distutils.html).

Answer (score 0):

More precisely, it may be the product of the distutils bdist_winsinst command, or the bdist_msi command, or maybe the product of py2exe, a third-party project building on distutils.